# Why was my question put on hold as being unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/48043/27924) some time ago and just realized that it had been marked as on-hold for being unclear. In what way was my question unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged it [lord-of-the-rings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) while asking about components and mechanisms that don't exist in that game.

It's therefore unclear what you are asking about. Something that does exist which you've mixed up? A different game entirely, and which one?

Comment: I checked out the tag wiki as well as Reiner Knizia online. It seems that I _am_ talking about the same game mentioned in the tag usage guide!

Comment: It appears there are several versions of the game, with component variations. The pieces you call *runes* are originally called *shields*, and were not split between a "silver" and "gold" category. I suggest adding this clarification if you can, then I would support reopening.

Comment: Done! I also added an ISBN to clear confusion of versions and stuff...